# Как исправить ошибку signatures do not match the previously installed version?

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, signature

> signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!

Comment: удалить старый apk

Comment: его нет на устройстве

Answer (score 2):

Вы пытаетесь установить на девайс `APK` файл с пакетом, идентичным установленному уже на девайсе приложению и с версией >= установленному на девайсе приложению, но с другой подписью.

Конфликт подписей APK файла как раз и приводит к вашей ошибке. Вам надо подписать ваш APK файл правильным ключом или удалить уже установленное приложение.

Также это может быть глюком IDE, ADB или ещё чего. В этом случае может помочь переподключение девайса, перезапуск IDE и ADB

Comment: Как можно удалить старую версию? Дело в том, что ее нигде нет, я ее удалял уже, но похоже, "не полностью" удалилась.

Comment: @ДмитрийТрабо, если на девайсе в списке приложений её нет, то, наверное, это таки глюк какой-то. Попробуйте советы из последнего абзаца. Также может помочь отключение `InstantRun` фичи в настройках студии.

Comment: К сожалению, не помогает

Comment: @ДмитрийТрабо, возможно у вас девайс с возможностью установки несколький идентичных приложений на уровне ОС? Типа `Xiomi`? Если нет - нужны ещё какие-то детали ситуации. Ну или пробуйте перезагрузить всё подряд - комп, девайс, в студии сделать `InvalidateCacheAndRestart`

Comment: девайс Meizu m3

Comment: @ДмитрийТрабо, проверьте, что у вас не установлено ваше приложение в пространстве втором. Как - не помню, но видел такое. Также проверьте что не слетело ли что-то в настройках разработчика.

Comment: Можно пояснить, что есть "пространстве втором" ?

Comment: @ДмитрийТрабо, девайсы от `Xiomi` позволяют "раздвоить" приложения. В итоге на девайсе получается одновременно 2 приложения одинаковых.

Comment: Неа, никакой копии приложения тут нет (

Comment: @ДмитрийТрабо, ну, если никакие программы по поиску мусора не помогут то придётся сменить девайс) Других вариантов я предложить не могу.

Comment: Хотелось бы другого исхода сей проблемы)

Comment: @ДмитрийТрабо, если вы выполнили все вышеозначенные рекомендации и они не помогли, то попробуйте ещё `clean` проекту выполнить или сбросить девайс к заводским настройкам.

Comment: @ДмитрийТрабо еще бывает вариант, когда на телефоне несколько пользователей. Убедитесь, что удалили на всех аккаунтах.

Comment: Пользователь один, проект чистил

Comment: Еще можно добавить перезапуск ПК :D

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте `adb uninstall "ru.your_app.your_app"`

Comment: Сообщение «Попробуйте вот это» не является ответом на вопрос. Когда автор подтвердит, что это действительно сработало, тогда можно будет опубликовать эту рекомендацию с объяснением почему сработает именно она.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась следующим образом: с помощью приложения "Package Name Viewer" увидел, что на смартфоне есть базовый сервис, у которого package совпадает с package моего приложения. Пришлось сделать рефакторинг всего проекта, и проблема исчезла!