# Проблема при установке приложения на телефон

Tags: android, android-studio

Только установил Android Studio, запускаю простой проект, что бы проверить все ли правильно настроено и не устанавливается APK файл на телефон, вылетает ошибка

[image: Скриншот]

В логах

```
12/19 16:34:02: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t D:\Projects\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk D:\Projects\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk D:\Projects\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk D:\Projects\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk D:\Projects\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk D:\Projects\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk D:\Projects\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk D:\Projects\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk D:\Projects\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk D:\Projects\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk D:\Projects\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk D:\Projects\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk 
$ adb shell pm uninstall com.example.opimand.myapplication
Unknown failure (Failure - not installed for 0)
Error while Installing APKs
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/729974/11515

Answer (score 1):

Там написано, что тот пакет, который Вы запускаете, уже установлен.

> Installation failed with message Failed to finalize session: INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package com.example.opimand.myapplication Signatures do not match the previously installed version; ignoring!
>   It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

Для исправления ошибки нажмите ОК при вылетающем сообщении.
Если у Вас НЕ УСТАНОВЛЕНО это приложение (или одна из его версий), то попробуйте перезапустить IDE.

Answer (score 0):

```
Build -> Build APK(s)
```

Затем установить файл `app-debug.apk` через файловый менеджер на телефоне.