# Снова Package signatures do not match the previously installed version

Tags: android, юнит-тесты

Пытаюсь запустить `Xamarin ui tests` на эмуляторе но `apk` не устанавливается :

> [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE: Package `com.name` signatures do not
> match the previously installed version; ignoring!] Performing Streamed
> Install

Перед установкой удалил старую версию приложения через adb:

> pm uninstall --user 0 `com.name`

Результат :

> Success

Однако ошибка осталась. Посмотрел через `Package Name Viewer`, как советовали [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729967/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-signatures-do-not-match-the-previously-installed-version), обнаружил что `com.name` все еще присутствует в USERS APPS. В деталях приложения сказано `Not installed for this user` однако полностью оно не удалилось. Подозреваю что из за этого и не получается установить `apk`. Как можно полностью удалить приложение с эмулятора ?

Используется эмулятор Oreo 8.0 - Api 26.

**UPD** `com.name` - предустановленное системное приложение.

Comment: А почему `pm uninstall` **--user 0** `com.name`, а не `adb uninstall com.name`? Этим вы сами указали удалить приложение только для `user 0`, а не полностью с устройства

Comment: @woesss при вводе команды `adb.exe uninstall com.name` adb выдавал ошибку  `Failure [DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR]`

Comment: Попробуйте варианты из этого ответа: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/92130. В конце-концов эмулятор можно сбросить к девственно-нетронутому состоянию.

Comment: @woesss сброс эмулятора до заводских настроек не поможет, потому что приложение уже будет установлено на заводских настройках.

Comment: @woesss Соответственно его невозможно удалить через настройки.

Comment: Не понял - вы хотите заменить предустановленное/системное приложение? - тогда нет легального способа это сделать, нужно подписать его тем же сертификатом, как минимум, либо под рутом удалить и поставить своё, но тогда оно не будет иметь таких же привилегий, как оригинал, насколько я понимаю. И это нужно указать в вопросе - так в корне меняет дело.

Comment: @woesss я полагал что `pm uninstall --user 0 com.name` и есть удаление под рутом. И ведь это эмулятор, уже рутован.

Comment: Насчёт рут я не советчик. Но в одном уверен - если вы не подпишите системное приложение системным сертификатом, то оно почти наверняка не сможет работать. Ну и в маркете вы его  в любом случае не опубликуете (если вдруг вы это задумали).

Comment: @woesss у меня есть apk приложения, но оно не установится пока не будет удалено старое в этом проблема.